# How to chain pandas pipe operation involving 'index' manipulation?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I was doing plotting in pandas and encountered following issue with pandas chain operation

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

n = 365
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"A":np.random.randn(n), "B":np.random.randn(n)+1},
                  index=pd.date_range(start="2017-01-01", periods=n, freq="D"))

df1 = df.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['month','vars','vals'],axis=1,inplace=False).set_index('month',drop=True)

sns.boxplot(x=df1.index.month, y="vals", hue="vars", data=df1)
```

**How to do this using single pandas chain operation?**

My attempt: (gives wrong image output)

```
(df.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['month','vars','vals'],axis=1,inplace=False)
 .set_index('month',drop=False)
 .pipe( (sns.boxplot, 'data'), x='month', y="vals", hue="vars"))
```

Required Image:

[image]

**Question**

How to get the above looking image in ONE-LINER?

Comment: @Elmex80 I would like to get the final result as shown in figure in a one-liner, and I know my code is not working and that is the reason I am seeking help.

Comment: You are mixing the wrong things together. You just can not feed `sns.boxplot` to `.pipe`. What is wrong with the initial code ?

Comment: Why a one-liner? 1 line is not better than 2 lines.

Comment: I totally agree with you, multiple-liners is clean and easy to read and write. I am just practicing pandas and unlocking its infinite potentials and tricks.

Comment: You want to mix IO with stateless functions. That is in general not a good idea. The creators of the pandas package agree on that and therefore you can only feed "pure" functions to the `pipe` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want something like this, using lambda function to pass dataframe to sns.boxplot:

```
(df.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['month','vars','vals'],axis=1,inplace=False)
   .set_index('month',drop=False)
   .pipe(lambda x: sns.boxplot(x=x.index.month, y="vals", hue="vars", data=x)))
```

[image]